# Can I get the name of a JSON schema from one of its values using Python?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get a JSON sub-schema's "name" from based off of its contents. This is kind of hard to explain, so an example would be better:

```
{
 "dummy_name_1": {
  "dummy_key_1": "unique_dummy_value_1",
  "dummy_key_2": "dummy_value_2"
},
"dummy_name_2": {
  "dummy_key_1": "unique_dummy_value_2",
  "dummy_key_2": "dummy_value_2"
}
}
```

I want to get the name of dummy_name_1 (which would be "dummy_name_1") given the value of the key "dummy_key_1" (which would be "unique_dummy_value_1"). Basically, if I give the Python function I want "dummy_key_1" and "unique_dummy_value_1" as parameters, I want it to return the string "dummy_name_1".

Comment: can you make the JSON valid?

Comment: @Christian Sloper I have just fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? `structure` being your dict.

```
def get_dummy_name(dummy_key, dummy_value):
  for dummy_name, content in structure.items():
    if dummy_key in content.keys() and content[dummy_key] == dummy_value:
      return dummy_name
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
def get_category_name(key_name, key_value):
    dictionary = {
        "dummy_name_1": {
            "dummy_key_1": "unique_dummy_value_1",
            "dummy_key_2": "dummy_value_2"
        },
        "dummy_name_2": {
            "dummy_key_1": "unique_dummy_value_2",
            "dummy_key_2": "dummy_value_2"
        }
    }

    for elem in dictionary.items():
        if key_name in elem[1] and elem[1][key_name] == key_value:
            return elem[0]

    return False


response = get_category_name('dummy_key_1', 'unique_dummy_value_1')
```